# Internet speed drops when I download

Tags: internet-connection, bittorrent

When I download a lot of data I see a drop in my internet performance. Usually I download torrents. What might be causing this drop in performance?

Comment: Talk to your service provider. There isn't anything on your own that can be done to increase your internet speed except perhaps only downloading a select few torrents.

Comment: I have the same problem with my car. When I drive it a lot, it loses gas.

Comment: @kobaltz | You should see a mechanic about that ;) strange problem you have there ;)

Comment: I know what he's talking about. This is a rare bug with torrents, when you download files from a torrent, the rest of the internet basically shuts down. This happened to me for about a week, then magically went away. I don't entirly know why this happened or how the problem went away. This is a legit question.

Comment: @Sickest - Really?  Its not a "bug" with torrents.  Its your service provider throttling your connection because your downloading torrents.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are downloading torrents you could be getting throttled by your internet service provider. There are methods to test if this is the case. One I have used is  [Glasnost](http://broadband.mpi-sws.org/transparency/glasnost.php)

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/165481/how-to-test-if-your-isp-is-throttling-your-internet-connection/)

*Note* - This is one of many, many possible issues (other than the fact you are downloading a lot of data). More information will help us give you a solutions (if one is even required).